# Use GAP program to obtain explicit cocycles in group cohomology

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-cohomology, gap

I'm trying to compute group cohomology $H^n(G,\mathbb{Z})$ of some crystal groups $G$ which are infinite but finitely generated groups. I succeed in obtaining cohomology groups using projective resolutions, `HomToIntegralModule` and `Cohomology`. But the outcomes are just some abstract numbers representing Abelian groups. Is there any way of obtaining explicit cocycles using GAP?

Note: when the group $G$ acts trivially on $\mathbb{Z}$, I know that we have some way of doing it as in http://hamilton.nuigalway.ie/Hap/www/SideLinks/About/aboutCocycles.html. But I don't think this method works for the case where $G$ has non-trivial actions on $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I edited to the maths looks nice, if you didn't mean the integers when you wrote 'Z', please edit to fix.